# What are exactly shells levels?

Tags: linux, bash

My understanding of shell levels and sub-shell was that:

1. Sub-shells are forks (but not execs) of the shell process created by `( ... )` constructs.
2. `$SHLVL` counts shell execs.
3. `$BASH_SUBSHELL` counts sub-shells creation.

However consider the following example:

```
1: $ cat lvltest.sh
#!/bin/bash
pstree $1
echo "SUBSHELL LEVEL = $BASH_SUBSHELL"
echo "SHELL LEVEL = $SHLVL"

2: $ . lvltest.sh $$
bash───pstree
SUBSHELL LEVEL = 0
SHELL LEVEL = 1

3: $ ./lvltest.sh $$
bash───lvltest.sh───pstree
SUBSHELL LEVEL = 0
SHELL LEVEL = 2

4: $ ( ./lvltest.sh $$ )
bash───lvltest.sh───pstree
SUBSHELL LEVEL = 0
SHELL LEVEL = 1

5: $ ( . lvltest.sh $$  )
bash───bash───pstree
SUBSHELL LEVEL = 1
SHELL LEVEL = 1
```

I don't understand why line 4 output is different from line 3 output.

Line 4 does a bash exec and runs the script, exactly like line 3. It doesn't create a sub-shell (line 5 does).

EDIT:
**Bash version used for the test is 5.0.3(1)-release.**

Comment: I get `bash───lvltest.sh───pstree
SUBSHELL LEVEL = 0
SHELL LEVEL = 2`  for `( ./lvltest.sh $$ )` and `./lvltest.sh $$`, with bash 4.4.20(1)-release

Comment: `SHLVL` and `BASH_SUBSHELL` aren't very reliable, and the definition of subshell is hazy (subshell != subprocess). And `SHLVL` doesn't really "count shell execs": see `export script='echo $SHLVL; exec bash -c "$script"'; bash -c "$script"` -- stays at 2 ;-)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in bash 5. If you do `( declare -p SHLVL; ./lvltest.sh $$ )`, the output changes yet again.

Comment: The 4. example is different from 3. because bash optimizes `(simple_cmd)` to `(exec simple_cmd)`, and exec will decrement `SHLVL` (even when not using the `exec` builtin explicitly. See [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed#n5376). @muru It's not a bug, but a bugfix. Or something like that.

Comment: @mosvy However `( exec ./lvltest.sh $$ ) ` gives the same output as 3. (and different from 4.). Which doesn't seem very consistent to me.

Comment: Yes, the (explicit) `exec` builtin will only decrement the shell level when not called from a `(...)` subshell (it will decrement it when called from another kind of subshell (eg. from `$(...)`). See [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exec.def?id=6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed#n190). As to consistency, it's not really the strong point of the shell language or of bash in particular ;-)